# How to recover/undelete a deleted task in Thunderbird (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Tags: data-recovery, thunderbird

I'vedeleted a Thunderbird task in which I've wrote some important notes (delete button, inside the open task window). Now I want to ***recover the Thunderbird task*** in order to get the notes.

Is there a possibility to find the deleted task?
(E.g. for emails there is a trash-box -- however, for the task manager I did not found anyone.)

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution but you have to do it while connected within the same session:

1. open the task manager
2. press the Undo combo (usually Ctrl + Z) as many times as needed

Your task shall now appear at the bottom of your task list.

Comment: Thank you :) It's long time gone and I can't test your answer. Therefore I've only ranked you up. Best wishes.

Comment: Maybe you can create a fake task and test these steps : you will know for sure what to do next time ;)